# Adding new Tab to Order View page not displaying

Tags: adminhtml

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * MageWorx
 * Admin Order Editor extension
 *
 * @category   MageWorx
 * @package    MageWorx_OrdersEdit
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 MageWorx (http://www.mageworx.com/)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MageWorx_OrdersEdit after="Mage_Adminhtml">MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Adminhtml</MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>

        <events>
            <sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>convertOrderItemToQuoteItem</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item>
            <sales_convert_order_to_quote>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_to_quote>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>convertOrderToQuote</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_convert_order_to_quote>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_order_to_quote>            
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_quote_collect_totals_after>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>quoteCollectTotalsAfter</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_quote_collect_totals_after>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
                <observers>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_order_create_process_data>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>orderCreateProcessData</method>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_order_create_process_data>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
            <core_collection_abstract_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <amflags>
                        <type>disabled</type>
                    </amflags>
                </observers>
            </core_collection_abstract_load_before>
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block</class>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_view>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
                </rewrite>                
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <sales_mysql4>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_status_history_collection>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Resource_Order_Status_History_Collection</order_status_history_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </sales_mysql4>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>                    
                    <quote_discount>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_SalesRule_Quote_Discount</quote_discount>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
            <payment>
                <rewrite>
                    <method_ccsave>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Payment_Method_Ccsave</method_ccsave>
                </rewrite>
            </payment>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <payflowpro>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paypal_Payflowpro</payflowpro>
                    <direct>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paypal_Direct</direct>
                    <api_nvp>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paypal_Api_Nvp</api_nvp>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
            <paygate>
                <rewrite>
                    <authorizenet>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Paygate_Authorizenet</authorizenet>
                </rewrite>
            </paygate>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_payment>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Sales_Order_Payment</order_payment>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
            <ordertags>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_AwOrdertags_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </ordertags>

            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mageworx_ordersedit_resource</resourceModel>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>

            <mageworx_ordersedit_resource>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <upload_files>
                        <table>mageworx_ordersedit_upload_files</table>
                    </upload_files>                    
                </entities>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_resource>
        </models>

        <helpers>
            <mageworx_ordersedit>
                <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Helper</class>
            </mageworx_ordersedit>
        </helpers>

        <resources>
            <mageworx_ordersedit_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MageWorx_OrdersEdit</module>
                    <class>MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_setup>
            <mageworx_ordersedit_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_write>
            <mageworx_ordersedit_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mageworx_ordersedit_read>
        </resources>

        <template>
            <email>               
               <mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_template translate="label" module="mageworx_ordersedit">
                   <label>Order Edit</label>
                   <file>mageworx/ordersedit/mageworx_order_edited.html</file>
                   <type>html</type>
               </mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_template>
               <mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_guest_template translate="label" module="mageworx_ordersedit">
                   <label>Order Edit for Guest</label>
                   <file>mageworx/ordersedit/mageworx_order_edited_guest.html</file>
                   <type>html</type>
               </mageworx_ordersedit_email_order_comment_guest_template>
            </email>
        </template>

        <sales>            
           <order_invoice>
                <totals>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/sales_order_invoice_total</class>
                        <after>tax,grand_total</after>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit>
                    <subtotal>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/sales_order_invoice_subtotal</class>
                    </subtotal>
                    <mageworx_ordersedit_shipping>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/sales_order_invoice_shipping</class>
                        <after>shipping</after>
                    </mageworx_ordersedit_shipping>
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>       
        </sales>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>        
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mageworx_ordersedit>
                    <file>mageworx_ordersedit.xml</file>
                </mageworx_ordersedit>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <mw_add_coupon_block>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mageworx_ordersedit/observer</class>
                        <method>insertCouponBlock</method>
                    </mw_add_coupon_block>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
        </events>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
                    <files>
                        <default>MageWorx_OrdersEdit.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </MageWorx_OrdersEdit>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>

    <default>
        <mageworx_ordersmanagement>
            <ordersedit>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <enable_shipping_price_edition>1</enable_shipping_price_edition>
                <show_thumbnails>1</show_thumbnails>
                <thumbnail_height>50</thumbnail_height>
                <send_update_email>0</send_update_email>
                <hide_edit_button>1</hide_edit_button>
                <show_all_states_in_history>0</show_all_states_in_history>
            </ordersedit>
        </mageworx_ordersmanagement>
    </default>

</config>
```

Here is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * MageWorx
 * Admin Order Editor extension
 *
 * @category   MageWorx
 * @package    MageWorx_OrdersEdit
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 MageWorx (http://www.mageworx.com/)
 */
-->
<layout>    
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>

        <reference name="avans_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>avans_tab</name><block>mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_order_view_tab_avans</block></action>
        </reference>    

    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>

    <mageworx_ordersedit_order_history>
        <block type="mageworx_ordersedit/adminhtml_sales_order_history" name="order_history" template="mageworx/ordersedit/sales-order-view-history.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
    </mageworx_ordersedit_order_history>

    <adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_addcomment>
        <update handle="mageworx_ordersedit_order_history" />
    </adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_addcomment>

    <adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_deletehistory>
        <update handle="mageworx_ordersedit_order_history" />
    </adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_deletehistory>

    <adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_saveeditcomment>
        <update handle="mageworx_ordersedit_order_history" />
    </adminhtml_mageworx_ordersedit_history_saveeditcomment>

    <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
        <reference name="invoice_totals">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_totals_item" name="ordersedit" template="mageworx/ordersedit/invoice_totals.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
</layout>
```

Here is my: `/MageWorx/OrdersEdit/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/Avans.php`:

```
<?php
class MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_Avans
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    protected $_chat = null;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('ordersedit/order/view/tab/avans.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Tab label');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Tab title');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
```

Here is my: `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mageworx/ordersedit/order/view/tab/avans.phtml`:

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Hello its me!'); ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
        the content you want to show
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add new custom tab to the order view page in the admin panel but nothing appears.

Where is my mistake, can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure that you have `echo $this->getChildHtml('avans_tabs')` inside the template of `adminhtml_sales_order_view`.

Comment: Can you Please guide How we can create a form there that can upload an image to some directory. I have tried but when submit the form nothing happend